# Submitting dynamic ajax field

Tags: php, ajax

I have an an ajax drop down box that if selected adds another field to a form, this works but this new field doesn't get submitted with the form. Any suggestions?

findTest.php called via ajax

```
<?php
$work = ($_GET['work']);
if ($work == "Work1") {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>New work1<input name="newWork1" size="20" type="text"/></td>
    </tr> <?
} elseif ($work == "Work2") {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>New work<input name="newWork" size="20" type="text"/></td>
    </tr><?
} elseif ($work == "Work3") {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>No work today</td>
    </tr><?
}?>
```

Test.php

```
<?php
$page = '';
$answer = null; //clean start.
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
$new = $_POST['new'];

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    ?>
    <p align="center" id="infomessage">Test message <?= $_POST['Comments'] ?>
        and <?= $_POST['new'] ?> or this should be
        work2 <?= $_POST['newWork'] ?></p>
<? } ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Roshan's Ajax dropdown code with php
    // This notice must stay intact for legal use
    // Copyright reserved to Roshan Bhattarai - nepaliboy007@yahoo.com
    // If you have any problem contact me at http://roshanbh.com.np
    function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp = false;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e1) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getWorkDone(workId) {
        var strURL = "findTest.php?work=" + workId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('workdiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert("1 There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>

<table id="meters" width="800" border="0" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
    <form name="meters" method="POST" action="test.php">
        <tr>
            <td width="200" align="right">Work Done:</td>
            <td><select name="WorkDone" tabindex="14"
                        onchange="getWorkDone(this.value)">
                    <option value="Work1">Work1</option>
                    <option value="Work2">Work2</option>
                    <option value="Work3">Work3</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><p id="workdiv">New Work<input name="newWork" size="20"
                                               type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" align="right">Comments:</td>
            <td><textarea name="Comments" tabindex="40" cols="40"
                          rows="4"><?= $_POST[Comments] ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit"
                                                  class="button" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
</table></form>
```

UPDATE: new code.

findTest.php called via ajax

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['work'])) {
$work= $_GET['work']; 
if ($work == "Noworktoday") {
echo "<tr><td>No work today</td></tr>";
}  else {
echo "<tr><td>New ".$work."<br>";
echo "<input name=\"new".$work."\" type=\"text\"";
echo " size=\"20\" value=\"new".$work."\" />";
echo "</td></tr>";
}
}?>
```

And Test.php

```
<?php
$page = '';
$answer = null; //clean start.
if (isset($_POST['Comments'])) {
$Comments = $_POST['Comments']; } else {
$Comments = 'n/a'; }

if (isset($_POST['newWork1'])) {
$newWork = $_POST['newWork1']; } else {
$newWork = 'n/a'; }

if (isset($_POST['newWork1'])) {
$newWork = $_POST['newWork1']; } else {
$newWork = 'n/a'; }

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
echo "message = ".$Comments."<br>";
echo "newWork1 = ".$newWork1."<br>";
echo "newWork2 = ".$newWork2."<br>";
echo "newOther = ".$newOther."<br>";
}
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Roshan's Ajax dropdown code with php
// This notice must stay intact for legal use
// Copyright reserved to Roshan Bhattarai - nepaliboy007@yahoo.com
// If you have any problem contact me at http://roshanbh.com.np
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
var xmlhttp=false;  
try{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e)    {       
try{            
xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e){
try{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch(e1){
xmlhttp=false;
}
}
}
return xmlhttp;
}

function getWorkDone(workId) {      
var strURL="findTest.php?work="+workId+"&new1="+"&$new";
var req = getXMLHTTP();
if (req) {
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
// only if "OK"
if (req.status == 200) {                        
document.getElementById('workdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
} else {
alert("1 There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
}
}               
}           
req.open("GET", strURL, true);
req.send(null);
}       
}
</script>
<table id="meters"  width="800"  border="0" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
<form name="meters" method="POST" action="test.php">
<tr>
<td width="200" align="right" >Work Done:</td>
<td><select name="WorkDone" tabindex="14" onchange="getWorkDone(this.value)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Work1">Work1</option>
<option value="Work2">Work2</option>
<option value="Work3">Work3</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td ></td>
<td ><p id="workdiv">New Work<input name="newWork" size="20" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="200" align="right" >Comments:</td>
<td><textarea name="Comments" tabindex="40" cols="40" rows="4" ><?=$_POST[Comments]?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</tr> 
</table>
</form>
```

UPDATE edit double up and correct $newWork to $newWork1

```
<?php
$page = '';
$answer = null; //clean start.
if (isset($_POST['Comments'])) {
$Comments = $_POST['Comments']; } else {
$Comments = 'n/a'; }

if (isset($_POST['newWork1'])) {
$newWork1 = $_POST['newWork1']; } else {
$newWork1 = 'n/a'; }

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
echo "message = ".$Comments."<br>";
echo "newWork1 = ".$newWork1."<br>";
echo "newWork2 = ".$newWork2."<br>";
echo "newOther = ".$newOther."<br>";}
?>
```

This now shows n/a but not the value of newWork1

Comment: you post `findWorkDone.php?work="+workId;` and want to get it with `value="<?=$_POST['new1']?>"` : where is `$_POST['new1']` set ?

Comment: The whole code is 800 or so lines, I have only posted what I thought was relevant sorry about that.
The id="workdiv" is replaced by -> `New Work 1<input nam... value="<?=$_POST['new1']?>"/>` etc

`// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
 ?><p align="center" id="infomessage">"testing <?=$_POST[new1]?> <?=$_POST[new2]?></p>"<?...`

Comment: If this is to work, you must with another xy.php script first post the values to the script work_new.php . Without that $_POST['new1'] and $_POST['new'] are `null` . also $_POST[WorkDone] .

Comment: I have changed the op to just a test version with just what is not working, hope this makes it more clear. Thanks for your understanding and time :)

Comment: as I said your `findTest.php?work="+workId;` is wrong you need also the value  of `input name="newWork"` you only passing the value of workId but you need also $_POST['new1'] to set your value in findTest,php : `strURL="findTest.php?work="+workId+"&new1="+(value of input name="newWork");`

Comment: Sorry just realized I hadn't included the findTest.php correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have very modified the original question, I can only respond to what was previously.*

---

The important part is also `findTest.php`

from this script you replace your

```
document.getElementById('workdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
```

So how does `findTest.php` know about `$_POST['newwork1']`

```
<td>New work1<input name="newWork1" ... value="<?=$_POST['newwork1']?>" /></td>..
```

This must come via a GET / POST, but in your GET there ist only

```
strURL="findTest.php?work="+workId;
```

Only 1 GET variable named  $_GET['work'].

and you use this variable (without test)

```
$work=$_GET['work'];
```

And then you mixed the request from `$_GET` to `$_POST['newwork1']`

so why not use your select value to get it all together.

**Test.php**

```
...
<select name="WorkDone" tabindex="14" onchange="getWorkDone(this.value)">
<option value="Work1">Work1</option>
<option value="Work2">Work2</option>
<option value="Noworktoday">No work today</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
...
```

**findTest.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['work'])) {
//for example : $work == "Work1"  
$work=$_GET['work']; 
if ($work=="Noworktoday") {
  echo "<tr><td>No work today</td></tr>";
}  else {
  echo "<tr><td>New ".$work."<br>";
  echo "<input name=\"new".$work."\" type=\"text\"";
  echo " size=\"20\" value=\"new".$work."\" />";
  echo "</td></tr>";
}

//<tr><td>New Work1<input name="newWork1" type="text" size="20" value="newWork1" /></td></tr>
```

Update:

**You can not see your values because you did'nt `echo` them**
and you have to test all `$_POST`

```
$page = '';
$answer = null; //clean start.
if (isset($_POST['Comments'])) {
 $Comments = $_POST['Comments']; } else {
 $Comments = 'n/a'; 
}

if (isset($_POST['newWork1'])) {
 $newWork1 = $_POST['newWork1']; } else {
 $newWork1 = 'n/a'; 
}
....
```

and so on for all possible values

---

`echo` your variables

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    ?>
    <p align="center" id="infomessage">Test message = <? echo $Comments; ?>
        and = <? echo $newWork1; ?> or this should be
        work2 = <? echo $newWork; ?></p>
<? } ?>
```

---

Update:

I can not see the actual code, you need a `if (isset ...`  for all possible variables . In my example I have described only two possibilities. You need also e.g.

```
 if (isset($_POST['newWork2'])) { ...
 if (isset($_POST['newOther'])) { ...
```

and so on !! And make only asimple output.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 echo "message = ".$Comments."<br>";
 echo "newWork1 = ".$newWork1."<br>";
 echo "newWork2 = ".$newWork2."<br>";
 echo "newOther = ".$newOther."<br>";
 }
```

and put it logical together

This is illogical `Work2 assigned to newWork` !!!

Comment: Thanks for your response :) Yes I modified the original post to be a stand alone test piece so it would be easier to understand for trouble shooting. When I fill in the the new input box created via ajax and submit it I still don't get it being processed through to show on the message (like the comments is)
    `if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {?>
    <p align="center" id="infomessage">Test message <?= $_POST['Comments']?> and <?= $_POST['new']?> or this should be
work2 <?= $_POST['newWork'] ?> or <?= $_POST['newWork1'] ?></p><? } ?>`

Comment: If I select Work2 then in New Work2 enter massage and sample in the comments and submit I get `Test message = sample and = or this should be work2 = n/a` **not** `Test message = sample and = or this should be message = n/a`

Comment: I think I must be missing something totally! Now if I select Work1 from the dropdown and type in _sample-Text_ into the new inputbox (newWork1) and _message_ into the comments and submit it I still don't get _sample-Text_ processed through to `.$newWork1.` 
I just get message = message
newWork1 = 
newWork2 = 
newOther =

Comment: @user2698450 : must be at least `n/a` ! Put your new code of both .php files under your Question . Headline Update : new code or similar.

Comment: That's what I thought it should be `n/a` I have updated with the exact code I am using.

Comment: @bckspcer : Please be a little careful, you have a "network1" twice. Something you should double check before you post it. 2.) `$newWork = $_POST['newWork1'];` as you can see is wrong `$newWork` did not match `$_POST['newWork1']` !!! must be `$newWork1 = $_POST['newWork1']` .

Comment: Yes good catch have updated and tested now I get `n/a` but not the value of `$newWork1`

Comment: @bckspcer : Please update your new code (in you question) it's still the same .

Comment: @bckspcer : I told you have to echo in your code there is still `<textarea name="Comments" tabindex="40" cols="40" rows="4" ><?=$_POST[Comments]?>` **MUST BE** `<?php echo $_POST[Comments]?>` with `<?php` at the start. !!!!!!!

Comment: I have just tested in **IE** and it **works** but **NOT** in Chrome or firefox!!!! By selecting Work1 then typing "TEST" & "Sample" in newWork1 & comments IE returns `message = Sample newWork1 = TEST` Chrome/firefox `message = Sample newWork1 = n/a` ???????

Comment: @bckspcer : Yes it's true on , it doesn't work on firefox, but in IE it works. Now that we got it to work can you please accept my answer.

Comment: @bckspcer : i'm google for that, but found nothing so far :-(